# I need help integrating the Rest API data response into my graph

Tags: android, ios, flutter, rest, dart

I need help integrating the Rest API data response into my graph.

---

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GraphData {
  final String year;
  final int clicks;
  final charts.Color color;

  GraphData(this.year, this.clicks, Color color)
      : this.color = charts.Color(
            r: color.red, g: color.green, b: color.blue, a: color.alpha);
}

class Bargraph extends StatelessWidget {
  const Bargraph({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = [
      GraphData('A', 1242558, Colors.orange),
      GraphData('B', 4280940, Colors.orange),
      GraphData('C', 2942064, Colors.orange),
    ];

    var series = [
      charts.Series(
        domainFn: (GraphData clickData, _) => clickData.year,
        measureFn: (GraphData clickData, _) => clickData.clicks,
        colorFn: (GraphData clickData, _) => clickData.color,
        id: 'Graph',
        data: data,
      ),
    ];

    var chart = charts.BarChart(
      series,
      animate: true,
    );

    var chartWidget = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 200.0,
        width: 350,
        child: chart,
      ),
    );

    return Column(
      children: [chartWidget],
    );
  }
}
```

The above code was a static graph I am using. But I need to pass the Rest API array data into my graph.

```
 {
        "status": true,
        "message": "Graph Result",
        "result": {
         "graph-data": [
         {
                    "name": "Graph A",
                    "value": 661041,
                },
                {
                    "name": "Graph B",
                    "value": 2277460,
                },
                {
                    "name": "Graph C",
                    "value": 1565178,
               } ]
        }
    }
```

It's my Rest API data response.

The following is my API call, How do I pass the response array data into a graph.

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> apicall() async {
   // String propid = widget.value.propid;
    //print(propid);
    var headers = {
      'Authorization':
          '',
      'Cookie': ''
    };

    
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST', Uri.parse('***************'));
    request.fields.addAll({
      
    });
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    var streamedResponse = await request.send();
    var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
    final result = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("result");              
      }
    } else {
      print("called error");
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
    return result["result"];
  }
```

The following is my class model, How to use this model and response data to integrate graph

```
import 'dart:convert';
List<Graphmodel> graphmodelFromJson(String str) => List<Graphmodel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Graphmodel.fromJson(x)));

String graphmodelToJson(List<Graphmodel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Graphmodel {
    Graphmodel({
        this.name,
        this.value,
    });

    String name;
    int value;

    factory Graphmodel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Graphmodel(
        name: json["name"],
        value: json["value"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "value": value,
    };
}
```

I am facing some issues while integrating API array data to display a graph. so anyone can help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/charts_flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GraphData {
final String year;
final int clicks;
final charts.Color color;

GraphData(this.year, this.clicks, Color color)
  : this.color = charts.Color(
        r: color.red, g: color.green, b: color.blue, a: color.alpha);
}

class Bargraph extends StatelessWidget {
const Bargraph({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//     var data = [
//       GraphData('A', 1242558, Colors.orange),
//       GraphData('B', 4280940, Colors.orange),
//       GraphData('C', 2942064, Colors.orange),
//     ];

var data = apiResponse['result']['graph- 
data'].entries.map((e)=>GraphData(e['name'],e['value'], Colors.orange))

var series = [
  charts.Series(
    domainFn: (GraphData clickData, _) => clickData.year,
    measureFn: (GraphData clickData, _) => clickData.clicks,
    colorFn: (GraphData clickData, _) => clickData.color,
    id: 'Graph',
    data: data,
  ),
];

var chart = charts.BarChart(
  series,
  animate: true,
);

var chartWidget = Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: Container(
    height: 200.0,
    width: 350,
    child: chart,
  ),
);

return Column(
  children: [chartWidget],
);
}
}

final apiResponse =  {
    "status": true,
    "message": "Graph Result",
    "result": {
     "graph-data": [
     {
                "name": "Graph A",
                "value": 661041,
            },
            {
                "name": "Graph B",
                "value": 2277460,
            },
            {
                "name": "Graph C",
                "value": 1565178,
           } ]
    }
};
```

try this. Try to convert data from API into the given class before passing it.

Comment: @
Amit Gunjan Thanks for your response, still I have the issue while integrating,kindly revisit my edited code

Comment: please add the error you are getting. It will be more convenient.